# Java: Where to place declaration of final variable

Tags: java, final

I've been learning about final variables in Java from [SoloLearn](https://www.sololearn.com/Play/Java), and have stumbled across the following code:

```
    class MyClass
    {
       public static final double PI = 3.14; //defines a constant double PI = 3.14
       public static void main(String[ ] args)
       {
       System.out.println(PI); //prints 3.14
       }
    }
```

Why is the final variable PI declared before the main method?

When final PI *is* declared in the main method, the code gives an error: illegal start of expression, and it expects a semicolon between the words static and final. Why can't the final variable PI be in the main method?

Comment: Did you ask google?

Comment: I suggest keeping on with your tutorials for a bit before starting to post questions here on SO. Beginners questions are okay (provided they haven't been asked and answered before), but you still need to build your broad conceptual understanding before you'll be able to ask solid questions that fit with SO's format.

Comment: No offense, but i recommend continuing to work on your basic java skills. This is extremly basic stuff about variable scope (local, class).Short answer: It **can** be final if declared as a local variable. But local variables can of course not be static and/or public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the final variable PI declared before the main method?

Because the author of the code wanted `PI` to be a static member of the class, not a local variable.

> When final PI is declared in the main method, the code gives an error: illegal start of expression, and it expects a semicolon between the words static and final.

You can't have `static` on the declaration of a local variable. You could have just `final double PI = 3.14;` in `main`, but it would be local to `main` only.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the final variable PI declared before the main method?

It could be defined after, but fields are conventionally placed before constructors and methods in Java

> When final PI is declared in the main method, the code gives an error

Yes, because static fields belong to classes, not to methods. Methods only have local variables.

Read the [Java OO tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).